# Solr - Add terms to a facet

Tags: solr, lucene

How can I add terms to a facet in solr? I want to index some documents by a list of terms and synonyms.

I have text documents that contain terms that I want to be able to
 search on.

For example this document contains the following terms:

INTERFERON, CYTOKINE, MEC

I want these terms (or if the term is a synonym of a term in the term list, the preferred term [not the synonym]) to show up in the facet list of the terms I am indexing on.

> 1. J Interferon Cytokine Res. 2015 Sep 25. [Epub ahead of print]
>
> High Glucose Increases the Expression of Inflammatory Cytokine Genes
>   in Macrophages Through H3K9 Methyltransferase Mechanism.
>
> Li MF(1), Zhang R(1), Li TT(1), Chen MY(1), Li LX(1), Lu JX(1), Jia
>   WP(1).
>
> Author information:  (1)Department of Endocrinology and Metabolism,
>   Shanghai Jiao Tong University Affiliated Sixth People's Hospital ,
>   Shanghai Diabetes Institute, Shanghai Clinical Center for Diabetes,
>   Shanghai Key Laboratory of Diabetes Mellitus, Shanghai Key Clinical
>   Center for Metabolic Diseases, Shanghai, China .
>
> Recent studies suggest that histone modification is one of the
>   mechanisms regulating inflammatory cytokine gene expression in
>   hyperglycemic conditions. However, it remains unknown how histone
>   methylation is initiated and involved in  changes of inflammatory
>   cytokine gene expression under high glucose (HG) conditions. Our aim
>   was to investigate whether H3K9 methylation was involved in HG-induced
>   expression of inflammatory cytokines in macrophages. Expression
>   profile of cytokine genes under hyperglycemia in THP-1-derived
>   macrophages was determined by human cytokine antibody array. Based on
>   the results from the human  cytokine antibody array analyses, the
>   H3K9me3 levels of 4 inflammatory cytokine genes, including
>   interleukin-6 (IL-6), IL-12p40, macrophage inflammatory protein-1α
>   (MIP-1α), and MIP-1β under HG were determined by ChIP assays.
>   Furthermore, the expression of these 4 inflammatory cytokine genes
>   under either HG or chaetocin (an inhibitor of SUV39H1
>   methyltransferase) exposure or overexpression of SUV39H1 (a
>   H3K9me3-specific methyltransferase) was analyzed by  quantitative
>   polymerase chain reaction. Macrophages cultured in HG conditions
>   showed increased gene expression and decreased H3K9me3 levels of
>   inflammatory cytokine genes compared with macrophages incubated in
>   normal glucose (NG) culture. Inhibition of SUV39H1 with chaetocin in
>   NG-treated macrophages also increased the expression of IL-6,
>   IL-12p40, MIP-1α, and MIP-1β. Furthermore, inhibition of SUV39H1 with
>   chaetocin in HG-treated macrophages further increased  the expression
>   of these inflammatory cytokines. Contrarily, NG-treated macrophages
>   transfected with SUV39H1 plasmids show decreased expression of
>   inflammatory cytokines. Furthermore, overexpression of SUV39H1 in
>   HG-treated macrophages alleviated the expression of inflammatory
>   cytokines under HG conditions. Finally, HG also increases the
>   expression of inflammation cytokines in mouse bone marrow-derived
>   macrophages. Our data demonstrated that HG increases the expression of
>   inflammatory cytokines in macrophages through decreased H3K9me3
>   levels, which was partly mediated by SUV39H1. Dysregulation of
>   epigenetic histone modification may be one of the underlying
>   mechanisms for HG-induced inflammatory  cytokine expression in
>   macrophages.
>
> PMID: 26406561  [PubMed - as supplied by publisher]

EDIT:

I tried what was suggested:

```
but only got this:
"id":"9cae6e2f-bd81-4c72-b2a8-fd8184af603d",
        "_version_":1515690847909183488},
      {
        "content":["The CHO airport is at 38.1384683,-78.4527887.\nSee also: http://www.lat-long.com/Latitude-Longitude-1480221-Virginia-Charlottesville_Albemarle_Airport.html"],
        "title":["Test1"],
        "id":"cdf82556-7545-4d81-a7a5-83bb4f14e4b7",
        "_version_":1515776762744668160}]
  },
  "facet_counts":{
    "facet_queries":{},
    "facet_fields":{
      "key_phrases":[]},
    "facet_dates":{},
    "facet_ranges":{},
    "facet_intervals":{},
    "facet_heatmaps":{}}}
```

here is my query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/Cytokine/query?q=*:*&facet=on&facet.field=key_phrases
```

Edit2:
When I look at the analysis page in solr admin, I can see that it breaks up the the data in the whitespace filter and shingle filter but nothing in the keepword filter.
[image: screenshot]

Edit 3: Got it to work! Here is my schema:

```
<field name="key_phrases" type="key_phrases" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<fieldType name="key_phrases" class="solr.TextField" >
<analyzer>
<filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory"
            minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="3"
            outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true"
    />
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory"
            words="keep_phrases.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<copyField source="content" dest="key_phrases"/>
```

Here are my synonyms:

```
cytokine, CXCL10, cxcl10, CYTOKINE IP 10 PROTEIN, INTERFERON-INDUCIBLE PROTEIN 10
```

Here are my keep words:

```
endocrinology
cytokine
histone
```

PS: if you see that the copy field doesnt work you need to delete the data folder in the `solr/server/solr/[CORE NAME]/data`. Then restart and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the issues the field of Natural Language Processing is concerned about (NLP) and there are a wide array of libraries that does different sorts of NLP for most languages.

There's however a few small hacks that can be performed directly in Solr to do "[poor man's entity extraction](http://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/06/27/poor-mans-entity-extraction-with-solr/)". For your case, the second example in the article would be a possible solution:

```
<field name="key_phrases" type="key_phrases" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="content" dest="key_phrases"/>
<fieldType name="key_phrases" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory"
            minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"
            outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true"
    />
    <filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory"
            words="keep_phrases.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

.. where `keep_phrases.txt` contains something like:

```
airport 
restaurant
toy store
```

(or INTERFERON, CYTOKINE, MEC in your case). The `maxShingleSize` should be as large as the largest number of words in a single phrase.

For handling the synonyms, using a regular synonym filter should be OK.

Comment: I tried it, it seems to not work, Check out my edit. I tried with the content in the example and the keep_phrases.txt airport 
restaurant
toy store

Comment: Is there any content at all in your `key_phrases` field? Use the "Analysis" page under Solr Admin to see how the field is processed while indexing. You might want to adjust the shinglesizes as well.

Comment: This worked perfectly, and even works great with the synonyms. I don't exactly know why it was giving me an issue